# How set сommon size and clarity to all scanned photos (for about 550 pictures) in a Word document

Tags: vba, image, ms-word

I need to set common values to all pic in doc: **height: 29.47 cm, width: 22 cm; sharpness: increase to 50%.**

Already tried to insert into the **ThisDocument module** this code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim objInlineShape As InlineShape

    For Each objInlineShape In ThisDocument.InlineShapes
        With objInlineShape
            .Height = MillimetersToPoints(294.7)
            .Width = MillimetersToPoints(220)
        End With
    Next objInlineShape
End Sub
```

However, I've got an error "*Сompile error: Invalid an Immediate pane*"

Here is the link (5 pic in this doc): https://mega.dp.ua/ru/EMAy26

Comment: Readers should exercise caution when running existing macro/VBA code in Word document downloads.

Comment: Are you trying to run this code by pasting it in the Immediate Pane?  That can only handle single lines.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Sub Demo()
Dim iShp As InlineShape, Efct As PictureEffect
For Each iShp In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
  With iShp
    .Height = MillimetersToPoints(294.7)
    .Width = MillimetersToPoints(220)
    .Fill.PictureEffects.Insert(msoEffectSharpenSoften).EffectParameters(1).Value = 0.5
  End With
Next
End Sub
```

Do note that your pictures are likely to be distorted if their aspect ratios are not the same as the dimensions you're trying to size them to. To maintain the correct aspect ratios, you might use something like:

```
Sub Demo()
Dim iShp As InlineShape, Efct As PictureEffect
For Each iShp In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
  With iShp
    .LockAspectRatio = True
    .Height = MillimetersToPoints(294.7)
    If .Width > MillimetersToPoints(220) Then .Width = MillimetersToPoints(220)
    .Fill.PictureEffects.Insert(msoEffectSharpenSoften).EffectParameters(1).Value = 0.5
  End With
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

**macropod** sorry for late answer, was little busy...I tried to apply your code, unfortunately, got an error, attached picture below. Maybe I  am doing something wrong, so, if it does not bother you, please insert all parameters and send the finished file back. I will be very grateful for your work, because for me this book is very important.

Here is the link with file: *https://mega.dp.ua/ru/fP6mDT5e*